# How to create checkable ability to Qpushbuttons like QRadioButtons in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to add checkable ability to  buttons when clicking on one of them had the checked mode and the other buttons are unchecked.
That is, one button can be checked at a time.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
      QWidget.__init__(self)
      layout = QGridLayout()
      self.setLayout(layout)

      btn1 = QPushButton()
    btn1.setChecked(True)
    btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.61);")
    
    layout.addWidget(btn1, 0, 0)


    btn2 = QPushButton()
    btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 34);")
    layout.addWidget(btn2, 0, 1)

    btn3 = QPushButton()
    btn3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);")
    layout.addWidget(btn3, 0, 2)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you put an image of what you get now and another of what you want to get?

Comment: I want to have a few buttons that represent multiple colors.
For example, button 1 red
Button 2 is green and button 3 is black
Now, if I select the red button, the red button will be checked, and if I select the green button, the green button should be checked.
And the red button comes out of check mode

Comment: Make the buttons checkable with `setCheckable(True)` and add them to a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html)